# Send data via okHttp socket

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp, java-websocket

I'm trying to connect with `websocket` and the test socket is working `wss://echo.websocket.org` with my code but my WebSocket is not working and getting failed but whenever I try with the browser it works.

My Android code

```
 // val request: Request = Request.Builder().url("wss://echo.websocket.org").build()
    val request: Request = Request.Builder().url("wss://dev.xyz.co.uk/xyz").build()
    val listener: EchoWebSocketListener = EchoWebSocketListener()
    val ws: WebSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
    client.dispatcher().executorService() 

 private inner class EchoWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
        private var NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS: Int = 1000

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        Log.d("onOpen-----", "Socket connected!!!!!")
        webSocket.send("[5, \"driver106apikey\"]");
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"GoodBye!!")
    }
    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        Log.d("onMessage-----", "Socket connected!!!!!")
        Log.d("onMessage String-----", text)
        output("Receiving------ "+ text)
    }
    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
        Log.d("onMessage-----", "Socket onmessage!!!!!")
        output("Receiving------ "+ bytes.toString())
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        Log.d("onClosing-----", "Socket closing!!!!!")
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
        output("Closing : "+ code + "/" + reason)
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        Log.d("onFailure-----", "FAILURE")
        Log.d("onFailure-----", t.message)

    }
}
```

This is how data is sending in web

```
1. When you send data you send in this format : 
    function clickBtn() {
        var data = {
            event: 0,
            data: {
                lat: 123.2123,
                lng: 22.5543,
                status: 1
            }
        }

        conn.publish('driver106apikey', data);
    };
```

but trying to send with key-value in android is getting failed.

```
 val formBody: RequestBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("driver106apikey", "{
                "event": 0,
                "data": {
                    "lat": 123.2123,
                    "lng": 22.5543,
                    "status": 1
                }
            }")
            .build()
```

[image]

Erorr showing in android

> FAILURE Expected HTTP 101 response but was '426 No
> Sec-WebSocket-Protocols requested supported'

this is how data is sending through the browser.

[autobahn.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oIRHZamIaRGm_IQOZgHIU_qw4sYixSCY/view?usp=sharing)
[socket.htlm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxIJzMaMRNOp14gOfEmoK6HLv65QywXn/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

It seems OkHttp does not support WAMP protocol. I'd suggest switching to [Autobahn|Java](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-java) or similar library.

Comment: okay, I tried with `crossbario' but nothing happens

Comment: you should display what "nothing" was happening

Comment: Autobahn uses CompletableFuture, which rules out working on devices below Oreo. Pity they went with that decision. It's very Java 8 focused. Would be great if they had a compat version, and also a way to use either Wamp v1 or v2.